# How to set data for multiple UIpickerviews in Swift?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have `uiviewcontroller` with `uitextfields`, when users tap on the textfields `uipickerview` appears as shown in the attachment.

How can I make multiple `uipickerview`? For example, when the user tap on the countries textfields a pickerview shows up with countries array data and when users tap on the gender textfields uipickerview shows the genders array data and so on. I tried but only able to do it for one array which is countries as shown in my code. would appreciate if you could show me how to do it for the rest of my uitextfields.

```
import UIKit

class testVC: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var countries = ["USA","UK","Spain" ] 
    var gender = ["Male","Female","Both"]
    var language = ["English","French","Spanish","Other"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        var pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 100))

        pickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true

        var toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

       [![enter image description here][1]][1]
        var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
        var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "canclePicker")

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true


       genderTxt.inputView = pickerView
       genderTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

       countriesTxt.inputView = pickerView
       countriesTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

       categoriesTxt.inputView = pickerView
       categoriesTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

       startDateTxt.inputView = pickerView
       startDateTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

       endDateTxt.inputView = pickerView
       endDateTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

       languageTxt.inputView = pickerView
       languageTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

     func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

            return countries.count

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {


           return countries[row]
        }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        var itemselected = countries[row]
        countriesTxt.text = itemselected

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need multiple `UIPickerView`. Instead you need to set picker view data source based on first responder text view. Also you should implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` delegate method to reload content of picker view by calling its `reloadAllComponents` method

```
var pickerView : UIPickerView!  

override func viewDidLoad() {

     self.pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 100))
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: ("updatePicker"), name: UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification, object: nil)
}

func updatePicker(){
   self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if countriesTxt.isFirstResponder(){
             return countries.count
        }else if genderTxt.isFirstResponder(){
             return gender.count
        }
        // continue this way and implement all cases

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        if countriesTxt.isFirstResponder(){
              return countries[row]
        }else if genderTxt.isFirstResponder(){
              return gender[row]

        }
        // continue this way and implement all cases

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if countriesTxt.isFirstResponder(){
              var itemselected = countries[row]
              countriesTxt.text = itemselected
        }else if genderTxt.isFirstResponder(){
               var itemselected = gender[row]
              genderTxt.text = itemselected
        } 
        // ...


}
```

Comment: thanks for your respond, i tried to do it like you suggested, it worked except that when I go to another textfields the data in the uipickerview doesn't get updated. Do you mind explaining more about "implementing textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate method  to reload content of picker view by calling its reloadAllComponents method " thanks

Comment: @user3700449 check the edited answer and add the missing code in viewDidLoad. Also dont forget to add the `updatePicker` function

Answer (score 0):

You should add booleans to know what kind of data you want to pick, then you should check these booleans to know the array you want to take the data from, and when you open the picker view assign the correct values:

```
import UIKit

class testVC: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {



    var countries = ["USA","UK","Spain" ]

    var gender = ["Male","Female","Both"]

    var language = ["English","French","Spanish","Other"]

    var countriesFlag = true
    var genderFlag = false
    var languageFlag = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 100))

        pickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true


        var toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        [![enter image description here][1]][1]
        var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
        var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "canclePicker")

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true


        genderTxt.inputView = pickerView
        genderTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        countriesTxt.inputView = pickerView
        countriesTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        categoriesTxt.inputView = pickerView
        categoriesTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        startDateTxt.inputView = pickerView
        startDateTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        endDateTxt.inputView = pickerView
        endDateTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        languageTxt.inputView = pickerView
        languageTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

            return 1

        }

        //Add this delegate to know the clicked textview
        textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {

            if textView == countriesTxt {
                countriesFlag = true
                genderFlag = false
                languageFlag = false
            } else if textView == genderTxt {
                countriesFlag = false
                genderFlag = true
                languageFlag = false
            } else {
                countriesFlag = false
                genderFlag = false
                languageFlag = true
            }

        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

            if countriesFlag {
                return countries.count
            } else if genderFlag {
                return gender.count
            } else {
                return language.count
            }

        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

            if countriesFlag {
                return countries[row]
            } else if genderFlag {
                return gender[row]
            } else {
                return language[row]
            }

        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

            if countriesFlag {
                var itemselected = countries[row]
                countriesTxt.text = itemselected
            } else if genderFlag {
                var itemselected = gender[row]
                genderTxt.text = itemselected
            } else {
                var itemselected = language[row]
                languageTxt.text = itemselected
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: thank you. i tired what you suggested but it didn't work.